# what is the difference between the DEM Snapshot data/ Freeze frame and Extended data/Recorded data?

Tags: diagnostics, autosar, uds

In DEM while storing the fault data in the memory it store the info either in form of Snapshot data/ Freeze frame or Extended data/Recorded data. so what is the difference between these two and when it will be used.

Answer (score 3):

In short, while the FreezeFrame Data contain mainly event/monitor/environmental specific data collected by DIDs (e.g. temperature, speed, voltage), do extended data records contain optionally e.g. frequency/occurence counter, warmup counter, aging counter etc. managed by Dem itself.

See also the ISO14229-1 UDS Spec.

Answer (score 1):

The freeze frame contains data that represents the status of the vehicle when the DTC was reported (temp, speed, sensor values) the data isn't managed by the Dem.

The Extended data record contains data related to the DTC which is managed by the Dem (counters, number of cycles).